# Flying to the USA on BA - VeriFly app

Tags: usa, uk, british-airways

I'm flying from UK to USA on 1 December 2021 with BA.  Reading through the entry requirements [on BA site](https://www.britishairways.com/en-gb/information/incident/coronavirus/entry-requirements), I come to the part about verifly app:

> Get your documents prepared and approved in advance with the VeriFly
> app
>
> For a quicker and easier journey, you can upload your COVID-19 travel
> documents into the VeriFLY app before you check in online and arrive
> at the airport:
>
> 1. Check and update your Advance Passenger Information in Manage My
>    Booking.
> 2. Download the VeriFLY app and create a secure profile using
>    the same name as in your booking.
> 3. The app will prompt you to confirm
>    your flight details and ask you to upload proof of a negative COVID-19
>    test, vaccine certificate and any other required documents. (If you
>    have a connecting flight, please only add flight details for the final
>    leg of your journey. If you’re connecting through the UK, you’ll still
>    need to complete a passenger locator form separately).
>
> The app then
> checks that you meet your destination's requirements and displays a
> pass or fail message. You’ll receive an app notification and email
> with the full results.
>
> Once your documents have been fully verified, you’ll be able to check
> in online. Make sure you bring all your original COVID-19 documents
> with you during your journey and look out for dedicated VeriFLY
> check-in and fast track lanes.

Now, I really don't want to have to install this third party app (and in reality, I can't, as my phone is issued by the employer and I am prohibited from installing anything on it).  If I'm reading the above correctly, it's not mandatory and I can still check in at the airport instead.

I tried reaching out to BA on this, but couldn't get to the contact centre on the phone and received no reply to my email enquiry. Can anyone confirm the situation please?

If it matters, I'm flying "premium economy" class.

Comment: When BA messed up my booking for a return flight they offered me three separate and increasingly ridiculous automated excuses (1) for not accepting my phone calls. They did respond to a public tweet though it took them 12 hours. (1 "You're ringing from abroad on a UK number." Yes, how do you think mobile phones work.)

Comment: @GrahamNye wasn't Brexit supposed to put a stop to people ringing from abroad on UK numbers?

Comment: @phoog Why would you say that? If that were true, I wouldn't be able to call my home number from abroad.  Or are you referring specifically to the BA?

Comment: @AleksG it was a joke.  Right after Brexit there was quite a lot of "Brexit was supposed to put an end to" relating to lots of things that had little or nothing to do with the EU, including some non-EU European institutions of which the UK remains a member.  There was also some concern about the effect it would have on the cost of international roaming, but not in fact on the ability to roam internationally.  I was commenting on the ridiculousness of the excuse, which is indeed truly ridiculous.

Comment: Ah! So, Brexit it is then :)

Comment: @phoog I don't recall seeing that particular promise on the side of a bus. But this trip was pre-Brexit and within the EU (specifically, Lake Como).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'm still unable to get in touch with BA, even though I've been trying and trying and trying...  However trawling the net for any useful info, I came across this twitter chat where BA seems to be explicitly acknowledging that VeriFly app is optional.

[image]

If you don't use VeriFly, you won't be able to check in online, however you'd still be able to check in at the airport.

Just found this on BA site when checking my booking:

[image]

So, not mandatory.

*UPDATE AFTER FLIGH:* I flew yesterday with no problem. The VerifyFly app is optional.

Terminal 5 was a royal mess, but the "fast track" queue for those who used verifly app was clearly signposted.  Incidentally, it had about as many people as those without the app. All queues were very long and it took absolute ages for the check in agents to process each passenger.  I arrived in the airport about 3.5 hours prior to departure.  I took just over 2 hours to get my boarding pass and another about 45 minutes to get through the security, so I was inside about 45 minutes prior to the scheduled departure (which funnily enough was delayed by an hour due to the team taking longer to clean and sanitise the aircraft, according to the announcement).

Comment: US check in has been a nightmare long before COVID sadly.

Comment: @JonathanReez Not necessarily; some years ago I used to fly between UK and USA regularly (12-15 times a year) and don't remember this level of nightmare

Answer (score 6):

I have made the trip a few times during covid and confirm that VeriFLY was NOT necessary. The airports both ends wanted to see the print out of the testing certificates with all the necessary information. We offered the VeriFLY and they still wanted to see the print out certificates. There was some noise about a special queue for those with VeriFLY but we couldn’t find this.